# Error 101 (net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET): - Using PHP to parse statistics and load them into MySQL DB

Tags: php, mysql, apache, connection, web-scraping

Generally speaking, I am parsing hockey data from yahoo(http://sports.yahoo.com/nhl/stats/byposition?pos=C,RW,LW,D). Then loading it into a MySQL DB. I am doing this via Xampp(on my localhost) with PHP and MySQL started via its control panel.

I have also adjusted most of the config files in order to allow for extra memory, time, etc.. but please leave me possible answers in these areas.

**My error code is --> Error 101 (net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET) <--

Apache Log --> Parent: child process exited with status 3221225477 -- Restarting <--**

1) The code perfectly parses and acquires the necessary data.

2) The inserts(InsertSkater() and InsertGoalie()) also works perfectly into the DB.

(a) If I only "load" one of Goalies | RW | LW by themselves OR if I load Goalie plus either LW or RW, the PHP script runs perfect....
Simply, If I comment out everything but G and either LW or RW, then they will load and exit the script properly:

```
"working" Example Only(see actual code in lower box).
   $this->_hockeyDB = new HockeyDB();
   $this->LoadStats("http://sports.yahoo.com/nhl/stats/byposition?pos=G", "G");
   $this->LoadStats("http://sports.yahoo.com/nhl/stats/byposition?pos=RW", "RW");         
   //$this->LoadStats("http://sports.yahoo.com/nhl/stats/byposition?pos=C", "C");
   //$this->LoadStats("http://sports.yahoo.com/nhl/stats/byposition?pos=LW", "LW");
   //$this->LoadStats("http://sports.yahoo.com/nhl/stats/byposition?pos=D", "D")
```

The above would parse out data and load all statistics for G and RW. Then it will exit successfully.

(b) Here's the main problem: When "Loading" stats for C, D or any other combination such as:G, LW plus anything else would act as follows... The program will successfully parse and load ONLY what it can such as G, LW, then it would fail after the next call of LoadStats($url, $position). The Error causes an immediate exit.

```
 //For example:
 $this->LoadStats("http://sports.yahoo.com/nhl/stats/byposition?pos=C", "C");
 $this->LoadStats("http://sports.yahoo.com/nhl/stats/byposition?pos=LW", "LW");
```

In the above, All centers would be parsed and loaded into the DB, however, It would then exit and LW would not be parsed or loaded.

(c) I believe it may have something to do with the amount of data I am dealing with since this is a localhost operation. However, It will successfully run the first LoadStat even if i choose the url with all skaters (in total approx. 673).

Code is below:

--EDIT-- Removed code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Soo after a week of no responses, I decided to try a clean Uninstall of Xampp. Then I proceeded to install Apache 2.4 -> Php 5.4 -> MySql5.5 as per the following link:

http://lifeofageekadmin.com/how-install-apache-2-4-php-5-4-and-mysql-5-5-21-on-windows-7/

Worked unbelievably like a charm. Was able to simplify much of my code :).
To anyone still running into Xampp/Wamp problems, I highly recommend installing them the clean way. Learned a bit too!